# COM object instantiates from one program but not from another running under the same user

Tags: c#, windows, com, com-interop, com+

We faced a [rather strange issue](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6293047/57428) with our COM component. The component implements a well-known interface and is consumed by a third-party closed source product (hereinafter referred to as Product X). Product X is configured via Windows registry - Product X reads the registry and finds the class id of our component.

Our component is 32-bit in-proc implemented in native C++ using ATL and we register it with COM+ on 64-bit systems so that it is activated in surrogate process.

Now Product X fails to use our component and traces `E_ACCESSDENIED` in Windows event log and we also see the following error message

> The application-specific permission settings do not grant Local Activation permission for the COM Server application with CLSID {class id of COM object here} and APPID {app id of the COM+ application here} to the user MACHINENAME\administrator SID (SID here) from address LocalHost (Using LRPC). This security permission can be modified using the Component Services administrative tool.

in system log.

This looks like a problem with permissions. So we crafted a "Hello, world" program in C# that `new`s a COM component and calls one trivial (never fails) method from it:

OurComponent.IOurComponent component = new OurComponent.OurcomponentClass();
   component.TrivialMethod();

When that program is run from the same account as Product X it works okay - the component is instantiated and we even see the "green ball with a plus" spinning in COM+ console.

So we have two programs run on the same machine under the same user account and one can instantiate a COM component and another cannot. What could be the reason for that?

Comment: I'm sooo curious why this got a downvote.

Comment: Ah, those never ending COM access denials. I feel for you... I don't have any real suggestion, but I'm wondering: 1) Do you know how X is creating the instance? They might have some weirdness in the COAUTHINFO. 2) Any change if X is run as administrator? 3) Does your Hello World have the same bitness as X? (shouldn't matter, but who knows).

Comment: @eran: No idea of how X creates the instance. Both X and Hello world are run as administrator and both have the same bitness.

Comment: Maybe you should try the other way around then - create a non-trivial test app, play with the security settings of the instance creation, and see what gets you a denial. You'd obviously still have to find the solution given you can't change X, but it might point you to a specific setting.

Comment: @eran: Are there code snippets anywhere showing anything similar to what you suggest that I do?

Comment: I'm not a C# programmer, so I have no idea how that can be done in C#. In C/C++, CoCreateInstanceEx gets a COSERVERINFO parameter, which has a COAUTHINFO member. Using COAUTHINFO you can override various defaults like authentication level and impersonation level. Maybe some combination won't place nice with COM+.

Comment: @eran: Okay, C++ will do as well. Do you know of any code snippets that do something reasonable with `COAUTHINFO` on client side?

Comment: I know it doesnt explain why it does work on your example project, but just in case - did you try and change the activation & launch permissions of your com+ component?

Comment: @user4537: Nope, they have the default values.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are lacking the config for the app.

So two things for this to work. 1 Your app needs to be compiled as "Com Visible". 2 You need to register the com component (if not registered already)

Go to Start -> Administrative Tools -> Component Services. Expand Component Services, Computers, My Computer, DCOM Config. Scroll down and find the application . Right -> Click -> Properties and select the Security tab. You'll see some options here - the first block Launch and Activation Permissions - ensure that the Customize radio button is selected, and click Edit. Now, give the account you are using launch, activate, as well as remote launch/activate permissions. Reboot the machine (or restart the service/app) and hopefully it will work.